# Weird Neo4j Cypher query slowdown

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph with about 30000 nodes and 200000 relations.
Of the 30000 nodes about a 1000 are items, the rest are aggregates.

Each aggregate has a relationship `aggregates` to at most a couple of items.
I'm trying to find items that were aggregated with some items that I've selected.

```
START b = node:items('name:ball'),
      c = node:items('name:chocolate'),
      d = node:items('name:deck')
MATCH (magic)<-[:aggregates]-()-[:aggregates]->(b),
      (magic)<-[:aggregates]-()-[:aggregates]->(c),
      (magic)<-[:aggregates]-()-[:aggregates]->(d)
RETURN DISTINCT magic.name
LIMIT 30
```

I've never seen this query finish. This is weird considering that a query limited to just 2 items finishes in under a second.

```
START b = node:items('name:ball'),
      c = node:items('name:chocolate')
MATCH (magic)<-[:aggregates]-()-[:aggregates]->(b),
      (magic)<-[:aggregates]-()-[:aggregates]->(c)
RETURN DISTINCT magic.name
LIMIT 30
```

Could you point out problems with my query/schema? I know I'm doing something wrong, but I've no idea what

Comment: Your actual schema isn't real clear.  Are there a ton of possible matches off off the aggregates relationship for each of these nodes?  Have you executed this with the PROFILE keyword at the beginning of your cypher queries?  This should return profile information.  Try getting the profile of using just one item, then two. And note the differences